# How do I get a git conflict between a fork and the master branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I have forked a project, where added and modified files.

After a while, I realised that I should update a few configs from the master branch. I tried to git-pull the master and other things, and I ended up losing a few files (somehow).

Now I deleted the whole directory (probably not very smart) and I'm trying to load my fork from the last commit as following:

```
> git clone [URL of the project]
> git checkout [code of the last commit in my fork]
> git pull origin master
```

and all it says is:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

which does nothing, and doesn't implement any changes. I would expect some conflicts in some files, so I was wondering how do I get to that point where the two versions (my fork and the master) will show conflict (typically with something like >>>>>>>> HEAD ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sort of basic problem here: it's not *branches* that result in conflicts.  Or, perhaps slighlty better: branches are necessary, but not sufficient.  (But this also depends on how we define *branch*.)

To have a conflict in Git, you must:

- perform a three-way merge, using `git merge`<sup>1</sup>
- using two input *commits* (which will come from branches, but it's not the branches that matter here)
- whose *commit graph* results in Git finding a third *merge base* commit that is different from the other two inputs, and, last
- have both of the two commits have changes to the same lines of the same file(s).<sup>2</sup>

In all of this, the term *fork* is entirely irrelevant.  A fork is merely a clone with some special semantics provided by whatever hosting provider has given you a clicky-web-interface "fork" button, or web-accessible "fork" API.  If you forked a repository, you cloned it.  If you cloned your clone, you've cloned it again.  The important thing is which *commits* you have, by their hash IDs—which are their true names—even though you *find* those commits by branch names.

Every commit remembers the hash ID of its immediate parent,<sup>3</sup> which results in a backwards-pointing chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands in for some commit hash ID.  Commit `H` remembers the hash ID of its predecessor commit.  Rather than use a big ugly hash ID we just use another single letter to stand in for it, so we call that `G`.  So commit `H` *points to* (holds the hash ID of) commit `G`.  Commit `G` in turn points to `F`, which continues to point backwards.

Having made a clone, or just a bunch of commits in your own repository—all that matters are *commits*—you now have something more like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

The branch *names*, `branch1` and `branch2` here, hold the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  Git updated them automatically, e.g., when you used `git checkout` on the branch and made new commits, so that as you made the new commits, the branch grew and the name continued to point to the last commit.  So now they point to commits `J` and `L` respectively.

If you now run `git checkout branch1` and `git merge branch2`, Git will treat commits `J` and `L` as the two inputs that you provide, and will—on its own—find the best *shared* commit, which in this case is obviously commit `H`, that's on *both* branches.  Git will then:

- compare all the files in `H` to all the files in `J`—`git diff --find-renames H J`—to see what *you* changed, and
- compare all the files in `H` to all the files in `L`—`git diff --find-renames H L`—to see what *they* changed.

The merge operation tries to combine those two sets of changes, applying the combined changes to the files in `H`, so as to make a new set of files that can be used for the snapshot in the new merge commit.

If this combining succeeds, Git will make new merge commit `M` on its own:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

`HEAD` here indicates that this is the branch we're on, and since we're on `branch1`, that's the name that Git updates to hold the hash ID of the new commit `M`.  Commit `M` has a snapshot made by applying the combined changes to the snapshot in `H`.

If there are merge conflicts, Git stops without making `M` at all.  Git leaves a mess for you to clean up.<sup>4</sup>  You must do your own combining and then tell Git that you've successfully fixed all the conflicts and produced the *correct* merge result.  You then use `git merge --continue` or `git commit` (either one) to finish the merge and make commit `M` and the snapshot that *you* built.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git also uses three-way merge to implement `git cherry-pick` and `git revert`, as well as a few other special cases, so you can get merge conflicts without using `git merge`.  But `git merge` is the usual source and is what you're describing, so you can think of this as "when you run `git merge`" without too much loss of accuracy.

Note that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, typically `git merge`*.  So `git pull` is just fetch + merge.

<sup>2</sup>There are some sticky details on what "the same" means, both for files—which can be renamed—and for lines, which might merely abut rather than overlap.  But again, you can just think of it as "different change to same lines of same file" = "conflict" and be close enough.

<sup>3</sup>For merge commits, the commit remembers *all* of its parents—usually just two—and hence points back not only to the commit on the branch you were on when you made the merge, but also to the commit that was the tip of the branch that you merged, at the time you made the merge.

<sup>4</sup>The messy merge state occupies the *index*, which we haven't described here at all.  Git also leaves you its best attempt at combining the conflicting changes in files in the work-tree, and leaves information *about* the merge recorded for `git merge --continue`, which runs `git commit`, or for `git commit`, to pick up to make the merge commit.

You can back out of everything using `git merge --abort`, which puts everything back to the way it was before you started the `git merge`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Torek, looks like I should have a Git Tutorial, I might have confused a few concepts. I solved my problem, and what I basically did was generating a local branch with the same name as the one of my fork, which caused confusion. Also I didn't know that the master branch of a fork is different from the master branch of the main project, which was why I had this message saying that everything was already updated. I sorted these things out, and now it's working :) Thanks a lot again for your reply!

Comment: Right - each Git repository has its own branch names. When you `git fetch` (and `git pull` means *run `git fetch` and then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`)*, you get their branch names turned into your *remote-tracking* (`origin/*`) names. The fork style of clone copies their branch names into your fork's branch names, though.